# Using to SQL to transform and combine strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, text

Currently, I have an data set that is structured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    type CHAR NOT NULL,
    line_number INT NOT NULL,
    note VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
);
```

Some sample date:

```
Date, Author, Type, Line Number, Note
2015-01-01, Abe, C, 1, First 4000 character string
2015-01-01, Abe, C, 2, Second 4000 character string
2015-01-01, Abe, C, 3, Third 4000 character string
2015-01-01, Bob, C, 1, First 4000 character string
2015-01-01, Bob, C, 2, Second 1000 character string
2015-01-01, Cal, C, 1, First 3568 character string
```

This data is to be migrated to a new SQL Server structure that is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    type CHAR NOT NULL,
    note VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to prefix to the multi-line (those with more than 8000 characters when combined) Notes with "*Date* - *Author* - Part *X* of *Y* // ", and place a space between concatenated strings so the data would end up like:

```
Date, Author, Type, Note
2015-01-01, Abe, C, 2015-01-01 - Abe - Part 1 of 2 // First 4000 character string First 3959 characters of the second 4000 character string
2015-01-01, Abe, C, 2015-01-01 - Abe - Part 2 of 2 // Remaining 41 characters of the second 4000 character string Third (up to) 4000 character string
2015-01-01, Bob, C, First 4000 character string Second 1000 character string
2015-01-01, Cal, C, First 3568 character string
```

I'm looking for ways to accomplish this transformation. Initially, I had an intermediate step to simple combine (coalesce) all the Note strings where Date, Author, Type are shared together but was not able to split.

Comment: If you are going to combine those line, why don't you just use VARCHAR(MAX) on note, and put everything in one line? maybe that's easier solution?

Comment: @EricZ - Agreed! But I cannot redefine the structure, I'm not in the upper DBA echelons. ;)

Comment: How repeatable does this need to be?  It sounds like you would be happy with manual intermediate steps to get the transformation completed as you'd only be doing it once?

Comment: And can you guarantee that a multi line note will always fill all 4000 characters in all but the final line?

Comment: @iamdave - this will be done as part of a periodic migration, bit of manual / intermediate steps are acceptable. Where n is the last line, lines 1 through n-1 are 4000, n can be any length 1-4000. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, this was a bit of a challenge but I got there in the end.  Has been a thoroughly enjoyable distraction from my regular work :D

The code assumes that you will never have a note that is longer than 72,000 total characters, in that the logic which works out how much extra text is added by the `Part x in y` prefix assumes that `x` and `y` are single digit numbers.  This could easily be remedied by padding any single digits with leading zeros, which would also ensure ordering is correct.

If you need anything explained, the comments in the code should be sufficient:

```
-- Declare the test data:
declare @a table ([Date] date
                    ,author varchar(100)
                    ,type char
                    ,line_number int
                    ,note varchar(8000)
                    ,final_line int
                    ,new_lines int
                    )
insert into @a values
 ('2015-01-01','Abel','C',1,'This is a note that is 100 characters long----------------------------------------------------------'  ,null,null)
,('2015-01-01','Abel','C',2,'This is a note that is 100 characters long----------------------------------------------------------'  ,null,null)
,('2015-01-01','Abel','C',3,'This is a note that is 83 characters long------------------------------------------'                   ,null,null)
,('2015-01-01','Bob' ,'C',1,'This is a note that is 100 characters long----------------------------------------------------------'  ,null,null)
,('2015-01-01','Bob' ,'C',2,'This is a note that is 43 characters long--'                                                           ,null,null)
,('2015-01-01','Cal' ,'C',1,'This is a note that is 50 characters long---------'                                                    ,null,null)



---------------------------------------
-- Start the actual data processing. --
---------------------------------------

declare @MaxFieldLen decimal(10,2) = 100    -- Set this to your 8000 characters limit you have.  I have used 100 so I didn't have to generate and work with really long text values.


-- Create Numbers table.  This will perform better if created as a permanent table:
if object_id('tempdb..#Numbers') is not null
drop table #Numbers

;with e00(n) as (select 1 union all select 1)
        ,e02(n) as (select 1 from e00 a, e00 b)
        ,e04(n) as (select 1 from e02 a, e02 b)
        ,e08(n) as (select 1 from e04 a, e04 b)
        ,e16(n) as (select 1 from e08 a, e08 b)
        ,e32(n) as (select 1 from e16 a, e16 b)
        ,cte(n) as (select row_number() over (order by n) from e32)
select n-1 as Number
into #Numbers
from cte
where n <= 1000001



-- Calculate some useful figures to be used in chopping up the total note.  This will need to be done across the table before doing anything else:
update @a
set final_line = t.final_line
    ,new_lines = t.new_lines
from @a a
    inner join (select Date
                        ,author
                        ,type
                        ,max(line_number) as final_line     -- We only want the final line from the CTE later on, so we need a way of identifying that the line_number we are working with the last one.

                        -- Calculate the total number of lines that will result from the additional text being added:
                        ,case when sum(len(note)) > @MaxFieldLen                                                                                            -- If the Note is long enough to be broken into two lines:
                            then ceiling(                                                                                                                   -- Find the next highest integer value for
                                        sum(len(note))                                                                                                      -- the total length of all the notes
                                            / (@MaxFieldLen - len(convert(nvarchar(10), Date, 121) + ' - ' + author + ' - Part x of x //_'))                -- divided by the max note size allowed minus the length of the additional text.
                                        )
                            else 1                                                                                                                          -- Otherwise return 1.
                            end as new_lines
                from @a
                group by Date
                        ,author
                        ,type
                ) t
        on a.Date = t.Date
            and a.author = t.author
            and a.type = t.type



-- Combine the Notes using a recursive cte:
;with cte as
(
    select Date
            ,author
            ,type
            ,line_number
            ,final_line
            ,note
            ,new_lines
    from @a
    where line_number = 1

    union all

    select a.Date
            ,a.author
            ,a.type
            ,a.line_number
            ,a.final_line
            ,c.note + a.note
            ,a.new_lines
    from cte c
        join @a a
            on c.Date = a.Date
                and c.author = a.author
                and c.type = a.type
                and c.line_number+1 = a.line_number

)
select c1.Date
        ,c1.author
        ,c1.type
        ,c2.note
from cte c1
    cross apply (select case when c1.new_lines > 1      -- If there is more than one line to be returned, build up the prefix:
                            then  convert(nvarchar(10), Date, 121) + ' - ' + author + ' - Part ' + cast(Number+1 as nvarchar(10)) + ' of ' + cast(c1.new_lines as nvarchar(10)) + ' // '
                                    + substring(c1.note -- and then append the next (Max note length - Generated prefix) number of characters in the note:
                                                ,1 + Number * (@MaxFieldLen - len(convert(nvarchar(10), Date, 121) + ' - ' + author + ' - Part x of x //_'))
                                                ,(@MaxFieldLen - len(convert(nvarchar(10), Date, 121) + ' - ' + author + ' - Part x of x //_'))-1
                                                )
                            else c1.note
                            end as note
                    from #Numbers
                    where Number >= 0
                        and Number < case when c1.new_lines = 1
                                            then 1
                                            else len(c1.note) / (@MaxFieldLen - len(convert(nvarchar(10), Date, 121) + ' - ' + author + ' - Part x of x //_'))
                                            end
                ) c2
where line_number = final_line
order by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution considering the problem at hand. Kudos. I'm comparing it to the work in progress I have, not the same but some similar elements - I'll post something up so you can compare. Thanks!